# Github exyte Macaw-Examples swift compiler error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

The Github exyte Macaw-Example generates the following Swift compiler error:

[image]

I assume line 457 in SWXMLHash.swift may be the redeclaration.

```
455   /// Returned from SWXMLHash, allows easy element lookup into XML data.
456   public enum XMLIndexer: Sequence {
457      case Element(XMLElement)
458      case List([XMLElement])
459      case Stream(IndexOps)
460      case XMLError(IndexingError)
```

Comment: Sounds great. What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated these [Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/issues/143) and [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash/issues/140) issues on Github and also this [Swift 4 bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4951).
Long story short:

> Macaw is using the dependency SWXMLHash 3.1, which has this bug. The
>   fix is to use the latest version of the SWXMLHash (4.0 or similar).

**Easy solution**: use Xcode 8.3.3

**Change podspec**: go into `Macaw.podspec`, and change the line `s.dependency 'SWXMLHash', '~> 3.0.0'` to `s.dependency 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.1.0'`

**Otherwise**:

- [Download](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash/releases) last SWXMLHash framework version
- Copy `SWXMLHash.swift` and `SWXMLHash+TypeConversion.swift` from `Source` folder into your `/Pods/SWXMLHash/Source` folder.
- Fix errors (there are a bit of them)

But still, should you choose the last solution - consider risks with Xcode 9, because it is still in beta.

Comment: @Aleksei However, I can not debug the project. Breakpoints are ignored.

Comment: which way from listed above you chose?

Comment: @Aleksei The "Otherwise"

Comment: eh, that is a question I could not help you with.