# SWXMLHash.XMLIndexer:72:22: Invalid redeclaration of 'Element'

Tags: swift

When I use  AEXML in my project  it works in Swift 3.2 when I use Xcode 9 I have such problem with SWXMLHash. How to resolve.
[it's a mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3HhG.png)

Comment: May be a bit late, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723640/5754662) helped me with a similar error.